# Finding the training- and test-error for a glm-model

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, training-error

I have a data-set with approx. 200 000 observations and 10 predictors, with continuous target. I have divided this data into a training set and a test set (70%/30%).
I want to compare a glm-model against a random forest-model. I'm attempting to do so by comparing their performance on the test set.

I would like to calculate the training- and the test-errors for the glm-model.
So far I've tried 10-fold cross-validation on the training set:

```
library(caret)
train.control<-trainControl(method='cv',number=10)
model<-(target~., data=train, method='glm',trControl=train.control)
```

then in the summary, it says RMSE=0.2915827, is this the training-error?

How do I get the test-error from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RMSE reported by the summary of the model being trained is the training error. Think about it in terms of what that model object has seen; it’s only been trained on the training set.

To find the test error comparable to the training RMSE use the predict function and basic math expressions:

```
Predictions = predict(model, data=test)
testRMSE = sqrt(mean((Predictions-test$y)^2))
testRMSE
```

Where test is your test set of observations and y is the column variable you are predicting